# How to check that the function is not absolute continuous

Tags: real-analysis

I know when derivative of a function is bounded then the function is absolutely continuous but the converse is not true. How do you check to see a function is not absolutely continuous?. Further, how to check the absolute continuity when derivative of function is unbounded.

Comment: Each case is different.

Comment: Do you have a specific function in mind?

Comment: If a function is absolutely continuous, then it is differentiable almost everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

1. You check if $f$ is almost everywhere differentiable. If not -> not absolutely continuous. If yes, next step.
2. Denote the (a.e. existent) derivative by $f'$. Check if $f'$ is integrable. If not -> $f$ is not absolutely continuous. If yes, next step.
3. Check if $f(x)-f(a)=\int_a^x f' \, dt$ for some fixed $a$ and all $x$. If not -> $f$ is not absolutely continuous. If yes, next step.
4. $f$ is absolutely continuous.

Of course, depending on the concrete example you are considering, there could be easier criteria.